# unable to get $_SESSION variable

Tags: php, session, error-handling

[image: this error]

In **Log-in.php** I have

```
  $email=$_POST['email']; 
  $pass=$_POST['pass'];
  $_SESSION['type'] = 'user';
  $_SESSION['email'] = $email; 
  $_SESSION['pass']=$pass; 
  header('location:./connect.php');
```

I am getting error like
`undefined index email` for other user log-in, at other side I can log-in as admin here..

I have a log-in form that see rather what kind of log-in is this and pass that type in session in this **connect.php** its check what kind of type it is and then proceed it was working well but unfortunately getting error can't modify anymore.

log-in form is one form for user, admin and agents, where I am able to log-in as admin but I am not able to login as other it shows error

```
if(empty($_SESSION))
{
   session_regenerate_id();
   session_start();
}
@mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die("ERROR in SERVER");
@mysql_select_db('module') or die("ERROR IN DATABASE");

    $_SESSION['start'] = time(); // taking now logged in time

    if(!isset($_SESSION['expire'])){
        $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (60* 60) ; // ending a session in 30 seconds
    }
    $now = time(); // checking the time now when home page starts

    if($now > $_SESSION['expire'])
    {
        session_destroy();

    }

if(!empty($_SESSION['type']))
{
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$pass = $_SESSION['pass'];
$type = $_SESSION['type'];


// admin login //
if($type == 'admin'){




$admin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `email` ='$email' ");
$res = mysql_fetch_array($admin);
if($email == "" || $pass == "" || $email != $res['email'] || $pass != $res['pass'])
{
    header('location:./login/login.php');
}

}


// user login //
if($type == 'user')
{
     $email = $_SESSION['email'];
     $pass = $_SESSION['pass'];
     $type = $_SESSION['type'];
    $user = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `email`='$email' AND `status`='1'");
    $useres = mysql_fetch_array($user);
   // $trail = $useres['date'];
  //  $time = explode("/",$trail);


    if($email != $useres['email'] || $pass != $useres['pass'])

    {
        echo mysql_error();
//        header('location:./login/login.php');
    }

    else if($pass = $useres['pass']){
//        echo '<script> location.replace("./user.php"); </script>';
    }
}


// agent login //
if($type == 'agent')
{

    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
     $pass = $_SESSION['pass'];
     $type = $_SESSION['type'];
    $agent = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `sale_agents` WHERE `email`='$email'");
    $agentres = mysql_fetch_array($agent);
    if($email != $agentres['email'] || $pass != $agentres['pass'])
    {
        header('location:./login/login.php');

    }
    else if($pass = $agentres['pass']){
   //     echo '<script> location.replace("./agent.php"); </script>';
    }
}
}
else{
    header('location:./login/login.php');
}
```

In one way I am getting error in other way page is also displaying email 
**what to do now?** 
[image]

Comment: you show where set a variable to the value of `$_SESSION['email']`, but where do you set `$_SESSION['email']`?

Comment: just for information for you. `mysql_* function is deprecated`. Read this [article](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). The answer is your question is just like the error said that you have not defined index for email in session

Comment: @Sean i am using `$_SESSION['email']` for `$email` and using it to validating log-in in `SQL`

Comment: well your error `undefined index email` means that you have not set it prior to trying to use it in `$email = $_SESSION['email'];`. So where in your code do you do `$_SESSION['email'] = SOME VALUE;`?

Comment: `$email=$_POST['email'];`
 `$pass=$_POST['pass'];`
`$_SESSION['type'] = 'user';`
`$_SESSION['email'] = $email;`
`$_SESSION['pass']=$pass;`
`header('location:./connect.php');`

well that is like this @Sean

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Sessions Step By Step

1. Defining session before everything, No output should be before that, **NO OUTPUT**

   ```
   <?php
   session_start();
   ?>
   ```
2. Set your session in a page and then you have access in that, for example this is **page 1.php**

   ```
   <?php
      //This is page 1 and then we will use session that defined from this page:
       session_start();
       $_SESSION['email]='email@example.com';
   ?>
   ```
3. Using and Getting session in **2.php**

   ```
    <?php
      //In this page I am going to use session:
     session_start();
     if($_SESSION['email']){
     echo 'Your Email Is Here!  :) ';
     }
    ?>
   ```

***NOTE**: Comments don't have output.*

---

## Maybe answer to your question:

*I think you are not setting session, and because of that PHP doesn't know that session* variable.

> Your login should be like this

```
  <?php
  session_start();
  $email=$_POST['email']; 
  $pass=$_POST['pass'];
  $_SESSION['type'] = 'user';
  $_SESSION['email'] = $email; 
  $_SESSION['pass']=$pass; 
  header('location:./connect.php');
  ?>
```

Comment: @user4238306 OK, Please let mo to check it again

Comment: @user4238306 I tested in My own computer, But I did't found any error (I just found an DB error)

Comment: check images i attached with question, Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67369/discussion-between-multi-thinker-and-kermani).

Answer (score 0):

Set this code in login.php :

```
session_start();
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$_SESSION['type'] = 'user';
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
$_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
header('location:./connect.php');
```

And this one in connect.php :

```
session_start();
@mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die("ERROR in SERVER");
@mysql_select_db('module') or die("ERROR IN DATABASE");
$_SESSION['start'] = time(); // taking now logged in time
if (!isset($_SESSION['expire'])) {
    $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (60 * 60);
}
$now = time(); // checking the time now when home page starts
if ($now > $_SESSION['expire']) {
    session_destroy();
    header('location:./login/login.php');
}
if (isset($_SESSION['email']) && !empty($_SESSION['email']) &&
        isset($_SESSION['pass']) && !empty($_SESSION['pass']) &&
        isset($_SESSION['type']) && !empty($_SESSION['type'])) {

    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $pass = $_SESSION['pass'];
    $type = $_SESSION['type'];

    // admin login //
    if ($type == 'admin') {
        $admin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `email`='$email'");
        $res = mysql_fetch_array($admin);
        if ($email == "" || $pass == "" || $email != $res['email'] || $pass != $res['pass']) {
            session_destroy();
            header('location:./login/login.php');
        }
    }

    // user login //
    if ($type == 'user') {
        $user = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `email`='$email' AND `status`='1'");
        $useres = mysql_fetch_array($user);
        // $trail = $useres['date'];
        //  $time = explode("/",$trail);
        if ($email != $useres['email'] || $pass != $useres['pass']) {
            session_destroy();
            header('location:./login/login.php');
        }
    }

    // agent login //
    if ($type == 'agent') {
        $agent = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `sale_agents` WHERE `email`='$email'");
        $agentres = mysql_fetch_array($agent);
        if ($email != $agentres['email'] || $pass != $agentres['pass']) {
            session_destroy();
            header('location:./login/login.php');
        }
    }
} else {
    header('location:./login/login.php');
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

session_start();

```
$_SESSION["user"] = $result['full_name'];
$_SESSION["user_id"] = $result['user_id'];
$_SESSION["website_type"] = $result['user_id'];
```

// this is my code ...
// i cant access in another page ..

// second page `enter code here`
 session_start();
 // print_r($_SESSION);

```
    echo $_SESSION['user'];
    echo $_SESSION['user_id'];
    echo $_SESSION['website_type'];
```